# What is the usage of the GOOGLE_INPUT_CHEXT_FLAG in Google Chrome Web Inspector?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-inspector

Now a days I can see that just before the ending of the `</body>` tag something like below appears:

```
<div id="GOOGLE_INPUT_CHEXT_FLAG" style="display: none;" input="" input_stat="{}"></div>
```

I can see this in every webpages whenever I try to **Inspect Element** in ***Google Chrome***.

Anyone know about this?

Why is this?

What is its usage?

Can it be harmful to my data or computer?

Comment: Can you point us to a site that uses this?

Comment: I have edited my question for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have got the point. Its because of the extension: **Google Input Tools (by Google)**.

But I am not sure why they use that tagging.

Comment: Thanks! After I deleted Google Input Tools extension, that iframe disappears!